# The number of combinations involving an odd number of selected items equals the number of combinations in which an even number are selected

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Book problem:** Given $n$ items, show that the number of combinations involving an odd number of selected items equals the number of combinations in which an even number are selected.

**My interpretation:** We want to show that for any $n$ ($n$ even or $n$ odd) and any odd $j$ there exists an even $k$ such that

$$
{n\choose j} = {n\choose k}.
$$

**Question:** Am I interpreting this right?

Suppose $n = 4$ and $j = 3$. Then we should have that ${4\choose 3}$ equals either ${4\choose 2}$ or ${4\choose 4}$, but this is not true. It holds when $n$ is odd, but I don't see it for $n$ even.  Am I misinterpreting the question?

**Book:** "Methods of Mathematics" by Hamming

Comment: I think you are interpreting it incorrectly. The equality $\binom{n}{j} = \binom{n}{k}$ holds if and only if $j + k = n$. I think you are meant to show that $\sum_{i \text{ odd}} \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i \text{ even}} \binom{n}{i}$.

Comment: @DanielArreola How did you get that?  That seems like a stretch to me from reading it.  Is this some known identity?

Comment: Well the left (resp. right) hand side is the number of odd (resp. even) sized subsets of the original set of $n$ items. And yes, it's pretty well known; both sums equal $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ok, but how do you get the 'sum' of the combinations from the problem statement?  I believe you, I'm just frustrated once again, not with the math, but with the way it's asked.

Comment: Getting an odd number of items means getting $1$ item (there are $\binom{n}{1}$ ways to do this) **or** getting $3$ items (there are $\binom{n}{3}$ ways to do this) **or** getting $5$ items (there are $\binom{n}{5}$ ways to do this), etc. We add up all of these quantities to get the total count. Similarly for the even case.

Comment: What if $n=0$? Then there is $1$ combination with an even number of items and $0$ combinations with an odd number of items?

Comment: @Lucenaposition Indeed, we must assume $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @DanielArreola I get that.  Where in the language of the problem do you see that it says to get that total count as you put it? By "the number of combinations involving an odd number of selected items" reads to me like ${n\choose k}$ for some odd $k$.  That's the number of combinations involving an arbitrary odd number of items from the given $n$.

Comment: This feels like the kind of problem that creates "math anxiety".  Your interpretation is wrong, not your math, but then the teacher tells you you're wrong when not bothering to also say that under your interpretation you would be correct.  It makes you feel shame.

Comment: I get what you mean. But with combinatorial problems, you are almost always meant to count something and not prove that something exists. If I ask you a question like "how many ways can I do X", I expect a number as an answer and not a proof that doing X is possible.

Comment: @DanielArreola Still not sure how I would know that when in the very beginning stages of learning the subject.  Anyway, thank you for a little credit.

Comment: @DanielArreola The problem is now fairly easy.  Just expand $(1 - 1)^n$ which equals $0$ and then look at the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd.  You'll get alternating signs.  This avoids knowing what each side sums to, so I guess it's less useful or something.